# How can I see how much money I can send in Venmo?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Venmo has a [weekly sending limit](https://help.venmo.com/customer/portal/articles/1322662-what-is-the-maximum-amount-i-can-send-in-a-single-payment-):

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

How can I see how much money I can send in Venmo (i.e. weekly sending limit minus everything I have sent within the past seven days)?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.